# Не выводится svg-иконка через background-image CSS

Tags: css, svg, background-image

Почему не выводится svg-иконка, добавленная через background-image CSS?

Код:

```css
.icon-social{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.icon-social.big{
    width: 49px;
    height: 49px;
}
.icon-social i{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.icon-facebook i{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg id='Capa_1' enable-background='new 0 0 512 512' height='512' viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");

}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <span class="icon-social icon-facebook big">
     <i></i>
   </span>
</a> <span>- не отображается svg</span>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg id='Capa_1' enable-background='new 0 0 512 512' height='512' viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" alt="">
```

Дополнено:

```html
<svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z"/></svg>
```

[Ссылка на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyqn5j9b/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При вставке SVG через `background-image` нужно использовать немного другой формат:

```
// у вас используется encode и
// после декодирования получаеться
data:image/svg xml

// а нужно
data:image/svg+xml

// так же определенные атрибуты могут
// провоцировать данное поведение
// когда изображение вставляется
// через background-image
width='512'    
height='512'
```

```css
.icon-social {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-social.big {
  width: 49px;
  height: 49px;
}

.icon-social i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.icon-facebook i {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='Capa_1' enable-background='new 0 0 512 512'><path d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="icon-social icon-facebook big">
     <i></i>
   </span>
</a>
<span>- не отображается svg</span>
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста, что именно нужно поменять? `data:image/svg xml` у меня в вопросе с плюсом, если проблема только с плюсом

Comment: @word добавьте Ваш svg-код [сюда](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) и декодируйте. Плюсик пропадает, вероятно это и провоцирует проблему

Comment: @word в данном конкретном случае Вам не требуется использовать encode, поэтому в моем примере все работает. Но если бы там было что декодировать он бы так же не отображался как и у Вас

Comment: @word [URL-encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) Добавляет ещё готовые стили CSS

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, делал как-раз на этом сервисе, в результате не выводит svg

Comment: @word я в основном им пользуюсь, всегда всё получалось, но у вас же есть выбор, просто добавил для информации.

Comment: @Vasily, декодировал в предложенном вами сервисе, добавил + но ничего не выводит, также добавлял ;utf8

Comment: @word а атрибуты `width` и `height` убрали как я писал выше?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT у меня к Вам вопрос. Я считал что атрибуты `width` и `height` вполне работоспособные при варианте через `background`. Это браузерное поведение или это зависит от способа вставки?

Comment: @Vasily если `width` и `height` внутри SVG не указаны, то это то же самое что указать `width="100%"` height="100%"   Немного позже посмотрю повнимательнее этот топик

Answer (score 3):

@Vasiliy [комментирует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178778/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-svg-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-background-image-css/1178789?noredirect=1#)

> Я считал что атрибуты `width` и `height` вполне работоспособные при
> варианте через `background`. Это браузерное поведение или это зависит от
> способа вставки?

Нужно было только уточнить, - внутри SVG или у родительского контейнера.

1. Если внутри SVG в шапке `width` и `height` не указаны, либо они равны 100%, то SVG займет полностью родительский контейнер.

Ниже пример с одной и той же иконкой facebook, но с разными размерами родительского контейнера 32, 49, 64px

```css
.min-icon-social{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px; 
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.mid-icon-social{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 49px;
 height: 49px; 
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
} 
.big-icon-social{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px; 
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 512 512' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <span class="big-icon-social"></span> 
   <span class="mid-icon-social"></span>
   <span class="min-icon-social"></span>
</a>
```

2. Если ширина и высота иконки заданы внутри SVG, то иконка в родительском контейнере займет место равное её размерам.

```css
.min-icon-social{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 23px;
 height: 23px; 
 border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='23' height='23' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.mid-icon-social{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 49px;
 height: 49px; 
 border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='23' height='23' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.big-icon-social{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px; 
 border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='23' height='23' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m512 256c0-141.4-114.6-256-256-256s-256 114.6-256 256 114.6 256 256 256c1.5 0 3 0 4.5-.1v-199.2h-55v-64.1h55v-47.2c0-54.7 33.4-84.5 82.2-84.5 23.4 0 43.5 1.7 49.3 2.5v57.2h-33.6c-26.5 0-31.7 12.6-31.7 31.1v40.8h63.5l-8.3 64.1h-55.2v189.5c107-30.7 185.3-129.2 185.3-246.1z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <span class="big-icon-social">  </span> 
   <span class="mid-icon-social">  </span>
   <span class="min-icon-social">  </span>
</a>
```